# ConvertEmptyStringToNull does not work .net core Blazor project

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

In my class I have below

```
 public int recordref { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Required]
    public string disty { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Required]
    public string country { get; set; }

    public int claim_year { get; set; }
    public int claim_month { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string claim_no { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Required]
    public string partner { get; set; }
    //[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string sp_mdf_number { get; set; }
    public decimal original_claim_amount { get; set; }
    //[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_created { get; set; }
    public string created_by { get; set; }
    public DateTime date_updated { get; set; }
    public string updated_by { get; set; }
```

and my RAZOR page is as below.

```
@page "/adddebtor/{CurrentID}"
@page "/adddebtor"
@using BlazorAppDashboard.Data
@inject DebtorService ObjDebtorService
@using Blazored.Typeahead;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
 

<h3>Add Debtor</h3>

<EditForm Model="@objDebtor" OnValidSubmit="@SaveDebtor">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Disty</td>
            <td>
                <select @bind="@objDebtor.disty">
                    <option value="-1"></option>
                    @if (objDisties != null)
                    {
                        @foreach (var disty in objDisties)
                        {
                            <option value="@disty.disty_name">@disty.disty_name</option>
                        }
                    }

                </select>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Country</td>
            <td>
                <select @bind="@objDebtor.country">
                    <option value="-1"></option>
                    <option value="AU">AU</option>
                    <option value="NZ">NZ</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Claim Year</td>
            <td><input for="Name" @bind="@objDebtor.claim_year" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Claim Month</td>
            <td><input for="Name" @bind="@objDebtor.claim_month" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Claim No</td>
            <td><input for="Name" @bind="@objDebtor.claim_no" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Partner</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" list="textsearch" @bind-value="@objDebtor.partner" @bind-value:event="oninput" @onkeyup="autoComplete" />
                <datalist id="textsearch">
                    @if (partners != null)
                    {
                        @foreach (var pt in partners)
                        {
                            <option value="@pt.partner">@pt.partner</option>
                        }
                    }
                </datalist>



            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>SP/MDF No</td>
            <td><input for="Name" @bind="@objDebtor.sp_mdf_number" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Original Claim Amount</td>
            <td><input for="Name" @bind="@objDebtor.original_claim_amount" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><input for="Name" @bind="@objDebtor.description" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" /> <input type="button" @onclick="@CancelSave" value="Cancel" />
                @ErrorMessage
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</EditForm>


@code {


    [Parameter]
    public string CurrentID { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    
    BlazorAppDashboard.Data.Debtors objDebtor = new BlazorAppDashboard.Data.Debtors();
    List<BlazorAppDashboard.Data.Disties> objDisties = new List<Disties>();

    string temp_partner = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (CurrentID != null)
        {
            objDebtor = await Task.Run(() => ObjDebtorService.GetDebtorByRef(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentID)));
        }
        objDisties = await Task.Run(() => ObjDebtorService.getDistyList());
    }

    protected void SaveDebtor()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "";
        ReturnData rd = new ReturnData();
        rd = ObjDebtorService.Create(objDebtor, Convert.ToInt32(CurrentID));

        if (rd.status == 1)
        {
            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("debtorslist");
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Error.Unable to save." + rd.error;
        }
    }

    protected void CancelSave()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("debtorslist");
    }

    //autofill partner code
    private List<Partner> partners;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        DebtorService partnerdataservice = new DebtorService();
    }

    private async Task<List<Partner>> autoComplete()
    {
        DebtorService partnerdataservice = new DebtorService();
        partners = await Task.FromResult(partnerdataservice.getPartners(objDebtor.partner));
        return partners;
    }
    //end autofill code

}
```

When I submit the form, it won't convert null values to empty strings and give me SQL errors.

I do not wish to check each field one by one when I pass parameters to SQL. My parameters are below.

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disty", debtors.disty);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", debtors.country);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim_year", debtors.claim_year);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim_month", debtors.claim_month);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim_no", debtors.claim_no);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partner", debtors.partner);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "Pending");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sp_mdf_number", debtors.sp_mdf_number);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", debtors.description);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@original_claim_amount", debtors.original_claim_amount);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@created_by", "User Name");
```

Why am I still getting the below error

> Error.Unable to save.The parameterized query '(@recordref int,@disty nvarchar(16),@country nvarchar(2),@claim_' expects the parameter '@claim_no', which was not supplied.

As an example @claim_no field is not entered (no value typed in the box) in the blazor view and it should convert to empty string ?

Comment: Thie answer is in the name - `ConvertEmptyStringToNull`  **will** transform an empty string to null, but it **won’t** transform null to an empty string: _Users might enter an empty string for a field value. Use the ConvertEmptyStringToNull property to specify whether an empty string value is automatically converted to null when the data field is updated in the database._ - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.convertemptystringtonull)

Comment: When I say ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false, and if the user keep the input field empty without entering a value, then a blank value should pass in the object and back to the database and then the parameter value should be blank (not null) ?

Comment: The attribute’s purpose is “if you get an empty string, convert it to null’. You’re looking for the opposite behaviour - “if the value is null, convert it to an empty string”.

Comment: So `ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false` means “don’t convert an empty string to null” but it does **not** mean “.. but do convert null to an empty string”. And neither should it. That would be highly unintuitive. You need to find another way to do what you need to do. Maybe look up the source code for the attribute, you might find some pointers there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's that inconvenient to just do a null check.  It's only 5 characters more, and I think it will be easier to debug than to have some auto behavior filled in somewhere else:

**Method One: Null Coalesce**

If your SQL table's column is not nullable, and you really want to insert an empty string:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim_no", debtors.claim_no ?? ""); // null coalesce
```

**Method 2: Submit Null Value to SQL**

If your column is nullable, but you can't figure out how to pass a null value, try something like (you might have to tweak it, I'm at work and can't test rn):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@claim_no", debtors.claim_no ?? DBNull.Value);
```

Also, I VERY (VERY!) highly recommend using Dapper, so you can just list all the parameters you want in `new { ID = debtors.ID, claim= . . . }` and so on.  I usually avoid NuGet Packages, but I consider this one pretty essential if you're doing any database work.  I use many dozens of queries in my current site, and Dapper has saved me probably hours of my precious time.